# Implicit Differentiation questions?

Tags: calculus

How would I do these problems using Implicit Differentiation? I don't understand how to do them. Help?

> Find $dy/dx$ if $\cos(4x)-2xe^{4y}=0$.

AND

> Find slope of the tangent line to the curve $\sqrt{12x+8y}+\sqrt{2xy}=12$ at the point $(4,2)$.

Comment: You received some nice answers to your last question. You should accept one.

Comment: for the second one, it is -1. Just calculate the derivative and plug in values.

Answer (score 1):

Differentiate both sides of the equation with respect to $x$, remembering that $y$ is supposed to be a function of $x$.  So, for example, the derivative of $y^2$ would be $2 y \dfrac{dy}{dx}$.  Then solve for $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$.  If you are asked for the slope at a point, substitute the $x$ and $y$ values for that point in your expression for $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is homework, so I won't try to provide a complete solution to either of your questions.

If you differentiate your first equation with respect to $x$, you get $$
-4 \sin 4x - 2e^{4y} -8xye^{4y}\frac{dy}{dx} = 0 $$
which you should be able to rearrange.

If you differentiate the equation in your second question with respect to $x$, you get $$
\frac{12+8\frac{dy}{dx}}{2\sqrt{12x+8y}} + \frac{2y+2x\frac{dy}{dx}}{2\sqrt{2xy}} = 0 $$
and you can then substitute in your $x$ and $y$ values.

Comment: Where did the -8xye^4y dy/dx come from?

Comment: You need the product rule and the chain rule.  Be sure to treat $y$ as a function of $x$, not as a constant.

Comment: I'm still lost...

Comment: Well, if I'm going to differentiate $e^{4y}$ with respect to $x$, I need the chain rule.  I'll multiply its derivative with respect to $y$ by the derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$.

Comment: Excuse me @DavidWallace, just a question. I could also apply the Implicit function theorem?

Comment: I suppose you could; but then you wouldn't be using implicit differentiation.  The problem says "use implicit differentiation".